# mysql connection string to remote server

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have access to a database on a remote mySQL server. I can read the data from my local mySQL workbench.  I can also link to, and read, its tables using MS Access.
I have tried to use the following code in VB6 but are unable to establish a connection -

```
Set DBCon = New ADODB.Connection

DBCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient

DBCon.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=sherwood.unitingchurch.org.au;port=3306; Database=UCSData;User=UCS;Password=" & Pwd & ";Option=3;"
```

I have a copy of the mySQL database on my local computer and the VB6 program can see and use the data without problems, using the same code (but with localhost as the server).

```
Set DBCon = New ADODB.Connection

DBCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient

DBCon.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost; port=3306;Database=UCSData; User=UCS; Password=" & Pwd & ";Option=3;"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message?

I think your problem has to do with the driver.

Which architecture(32 or 64 bits) is your Windows,Office?